# How to Push looping data into an js array multidimention

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, push

I want to push looping data to array which format look a like `Array([2001,6],[2002,7],[2003,5])`

**MY data from JSON:**

```
myDatas = new Array([]);


                $.each(data, function(d) {  
                    var w =parseInt(data[d].datetime_end) ;
                    var c =parseInt(data[d].bor);


                    });
```

I want to push `w` and `c` to `myDatas` which look like that... Help me please master...